# Arduinino & Max7219

Tags: arduino-mega, spi, reset, 7-segment, max7219

I'm using a MAX7219 and 6 (six) seven segment displays
I used my own board and two purchased on ebay - no difference in operation.
MOSI, and CLK are correct and verified with my scope (Tektronics)
CS (chip select) is pin 22 (for no particular reason) SPI is set to Mode0
Yes, I have tried other pins as CS - all work the same.
My MEGA board can be powered by USB or 9.9 VDC wall-wart - no difference
Trial code is shown below, and works properly.
Placed 47 uF 50V cap on display board between +5 and GND - no effect
Placed 220 uF 35V cap on display board between +5 and GND - no effect
MOSI, SCK and CS are verified with scope to be 5 VDC. Compiler and D/L applications are set to MEGA and seem to work properly.

**PROBLEM IS THIS:**
Code compiles and D/L properly into Mega. Mega resets, and about 50% of the time all digits illuminate (not executing code properly?) Digit 0 (most right hand digit is enabled) never works. I can press the reset on the Mega as many times as I want - no effect.

**HOWEVER** if I pull either +5 or GND to the MAX7219 module, and reset my Mega, it works perfectly. Yes, this is obviously a reset problem, but I've never seen a reset problem before with the MAX7219. I put delays at the beginning at short delays in the SPI communications to no effect.

Has anyone ever seen anything like this before? I have no hair left to pull. I'm thinking maybe to use a MOSFET to turn the MAX7219 on after the MEGA is up and running. Any suggestions are appreciated.

```cpp
 //version 0.1
 #include <SPI.h>
 #define LOAD_PIN 22

 void maxTransfer(uint8_t address, uint8_t value) {

 digitalWrite(LOAD_PIN, LOW);      // Ensure LOAD/CS is enabled (LOW)
 SPI.transfer(address);            // Send the register address
 SPI.transfer(value);              // Send the value
 digitalWrite(LOAD_PIN, HIGH);     // Tell chip to toggle in data

}

void setup() {

 pinMode(LOAD_PIN, OUTPUT);          // Set port pin to output

                 // Reverse the SPI transfer to send the MSB first  
 SPI.beginTransaction(SPISettings(10000000, MSBFIRST, SPI_MODE0)); 

                 // Start SPI with attributes in "SPI.beginTransaction"
delay(250); 
SPI.begin();
 maxTransfer(0x09, 0xFF);           // Enable mode B
 maxTransfer(0x0A, 0x0F);            // Use highest intensity
 maxTransfer(0x0B, 0x00);           // Only scan digit 0
 maxTransfer(0x0C, 0x01);            // Turn on chip
}

void loop() {

  // Loop through each code
  for (uint8_t i = 0; i < 0x10; ++i)
  {
    maxTransfer(0x01, i);
    delay(50);
  }
}
```

Comment: Try adding a pull-down resistor to the CS pin. That way the pin isn't floating during power-up.

Comment: @Gerben - I added a pulldown resistor and it improved the reset about 50% of the time. Under SPI.begin I added:

maxTransfer(0x00, 0x0);           // flush SPI

and now it resets properly each time. I don't know how I missed these things! Thank you very much for your help.